# Reading raw data from a device that is not mounted

Tags: c++, windows

I'm attempting to read from an SD card raw data that is not formatted in a file system that Windows recognizes.

Using the `mountvol` command in Command Prompt I am able to get the `VolumeID` which I am attempting to use to access and read from the device, yet I have had no success.

I am attempting to do this in C/C++. I have tried to `fopen` the `VolumeID` and I have attempted to use `CreateFile` to get a handle and use that.

Any ideas on what else I can try?  I know you can open a volume directly using the 'start' command in Command Prompt, so I have to believe there is a way to do this.

Examples:

```
LPCTSTR test = L"\\\\\?\\Volume{501d29da-6d6d-48ab-a8bc-e14a7da74e9f}\\";

HANDLE file_handle = CreateFile(
  test
  , GENERIC_READ
  , FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE
  , NULL
  , OPEN_EXISTING
  , FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS
  , NULL);
```

OR

```
FILE *volume = fopen("\\\\\?\\Volume{501d29da-6d6d-48ab-a8bc-e14a7da74e9f}\\", "r");
long long offset = 0;  // Sector-aligned offset
setbuf(volume, NULL);  // Disable buffering
```

Comment: Sorry I can't help here, still it might be a good idea to add the failed attempts in form of [mcve] -- code often tells people more than descriptions.

Comment: I've added some additional information and removed one of the flags.

Comment: That's great, I hope someone can make good use of it and actually provide an answer!

Comment: remove `"\\"` in the end. use `L"\\\\\?\\Volume{501d29da-6d6d-48ab-a8bc-e14a7da74e9f}"` in `CreateFile` call. and what error return `CreateFile` ?

Comment: Removing the trailing "\\" at the end and putting the value in the call changed the error.  Now I'm getting Access is denied since I'm not an administrator on this machine. I appreciate the help and will report back if things to appear to start working or if I have more issues!

Comment: if you have not access - what you want ?